# Range Selector for the Y-axis in dygraphs

Tags: javascript, html, css, dygraphs

I want to show the Range selector for Y-axis in dygraphs. Normally we use `showRangeSelector: true`. Then it shows range selector for the X-axis.Is there any option to show Range selector for Y-axis in dygraps?

Comment: Nope! But pull requests are welcome.

Comment: Thank You @danvk